# java stringbuilder adding extra characters newbie questions

Tags: java, string, append, immutability, stringbuilder

I am a newbie to Java.  I wrote the following program and got the output below.

OUTPUT:

1

a out=

x=0 1 test..

x=1 1 gotcha..

If strings are immutable, how come I can apparently change the value of "thisCycle" from "0" to "1" and it prints out the new string value?
Why do I get 2 lines of output in the "for" loop?
Why does the first string have 2 periods appended to it?

Thanks

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    private static final ArrayList<String> ListContents=new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String thisCycle="Cycle";
         thisCycle="0";
        // advance to next cycle
         if (thisCycle.equals("0")) thisCycle="1";
        System.out.println(thisCycle);
        //
        String a1="test";
        String a2="gotcha";
        ListContents.add(a1);
        ListContents.add(a2);
        StringBuilder a_out=new StringBuilder("");
        System.out.println("a out="+a_out);
        for(int x=0;ListContents.size()>x;x++) {
            a_out.delete(0, a_out.length()+1);
            if (thisCycle.equals("0")) a_out.append(ListContents.get(x)).append(".     ");
            if (thisCycle.equals("1")) a_out.append(ListContents.get(x)).append("..    ");          
            System.out.println("x="+x+" "+thisCycle+" "+a_out);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings themselves are immutable, but you're changing the String value of a variable, not the String itself.  That's an important difference - everything in Java is done by reference.

You got two lines of output because the loop executes twice, because you have two elements in ListContents.

Comment: but the loop has 2 if stmts.  only one of the if stmts can be true, correct?

Answer (score 0):

String(s) are immutable. You're changing the reference.

```
String thisCycle="Cycle";
thisCycle="0"; // <-- changes the thisCycle reference.
```

To prevent that, mark the `String` as final.

```
final String thisCycle="Cycle";
thisCycle="0"; // <-- compiler error. Can't change a final reference.
```

You get two lines of output because your `ListContents` contains two String(s). Finally, you get the two periods because this

```
if (thisCycle.equals("0")) thisCycle="1"; // <-- changes "0" to "1"
```

Comment: i get the "final" idea.  somewhat.  but, don't i don't see why i get 2 lines of output.  how is the variable equal to 2 things at once?  even if i changed the reference, then the old reference should be gone, right?

Comment: @user2475400 `if (thisCycle.equals("1")) a_out.append(ListContents.get(x)).append("..    ");` is why you get two periods. You get two lines because of `for(int x=0;ListContents.size()>x;x++) {`

Comment: but, i have 2 if stmts.  how is "thisCycle" equal to 0 and 1 at the same time?  and, the 1st if has append with only one "." but prints out "..".

Comment: Because `thisCycle` isn't equal to 0. `thisCycle` is equal to 1. And that appends two periods.

Comment: yes.  thisCycle is equal to 1. and, when equal to 1, it appends two periods.  exactly my intention.  then, the first if stmt shouldn't do anything, right?  i shouldn't get this output:  "x=0 1 test.. "  i should only get "x=1 1 gotcha.."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this takes a little bit of thought to get your head round.

Think of it like this. A variable name is a bit like a *label* that you can put on a box; the contents of the variable is whatever's in the box. An *immutable* object means that once you've got the box and put something in it, the box is then sealed: you can look inside it, but you can't change the contents.

What you're doing in your code is changing what your `String` variable is pointing to; in other words, rather than changing the contents of the box, you're getting a new box, putting the modified contents in there, and the moving the label onto the new box. The old box contains exactly what it always did (it's immutable); but the label is now on the new box, and any attempt to access that variable will result in looking in the new box.